# python matplotlib bars graph size

Tags: python, matplotlib

so I ran into a few problems while showing the graph
first all the data is on each other I use strings at my x-axis and it looks like this
[image: the graph I'm generating]

so I wondered if there is a way to stretch it so It won't be on each other

and my second question is if there is a way to open the graph at full screen (I maximized it manually fo the pic)

and the code I wrote to show the graph

---

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))


names_list = [ i.split("-")[0] for i in self.data_dict["data"].split(",")]

values_list = [ i.split("-")[[1]] for i in self.data_dict["data"].split(",")]

plt.subplot(132)

plt.bar(names_list[::-1], values_list[::-1])

plt.suptitle('most commen words ')

plt.show()
```

Comment: You can increase the `figsize`, try `plt.figure(figsize=(40, 20))`

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate the x-tick values using the following line:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

That should make your labels visible. If I understand correctly, you want to increase the size of your figure ? You can do so, by increasing the figsize. For example:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 20))
```

Comment: I used the rotation and they are more visible but is there a way to make more space between them because they are still unreadable